# Animation disappearing on Old iPad Webkit

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

My CSS3 animation seems to work fine on all devices except it disappears on old iPad / safari and I don't know why:-

```
@-webkit-keyframes rollIn {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
}
}

@keyframes rollIn {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg);
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
}
}

.rollIn {
-webkit-animation-name: rollIn;
      animation-name: rollIn;
}
```

Triggered by

```
a {

                      -webkit-animation: rollIn 1s linear 0s 1 forwards;
 -moz-animation: rollIn 1s linear 0s 1 forwards;
   -o-animation: rollIn 1s linear 0s 1 forwards;
      animation: rollIn 1s linear 0s 1 forwards;
    }
```

The animation runs through and then disappears for some unknown reason?

Thanks
Glennyboy

Comment: what is the version number of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the css.

Managed to fix this by ensuring that all the CSS was in one file (previously separate) and also that Hardware Acceleration for the animation was enabled. I like to use the following combo:-

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```